# Compacting mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

With the mongo shell, I am doing something in a way which I think should be simpler. I make a first request to get a result needed for a second one.

Here is the first command:

```
MongoDB -prompt-:PRIMARY> db.Collection.find({"_p_unit":"TopCollection$npsV9rp1Gg","Order":2},{"_id":0,"AUDIO":1})
{ "AUDIO" : "audio_file_key_1a2b3c_Voice.bin" }
```

I use this result in the next command:

```
MongoDB -prompt-:PRIMARY> db.Collection.updateOne({"_p_unit":"TopCollection$BTDGm5LIcX","Order":2},{"$set":{ "AUDIO" : "audio_file_key_1a2b3c_Voice.bin" }})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
MongoDB -prompt-:PRIMARY>
```

Now this is my question:

Is there a way to group the two commands above into one?

Though I tried a few ideas coming up my mind, nothing worked.

Comment: so you want to UPDATE and SELECT at the same time?

Comment: The update method has a _filter_ (the query part) and the _update_ part. So, you can incorporate the two into the update itself. There are [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/) in the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: @Book_Of_Zeus. It is not UPDATE and SELECT at the same time. It is SELECT and then using this result to UPDATE.

Comment: @prasad_.  I looked at the link you mention, but I didn't see this kind of combination like the one I am making. Beside I am using the query part and the update part, in my second command. That does not make the first command result coming in the second, which is what I would like.

Comment: To update using the document's data you need to use the **Updates with Aggregation Pipeline** option (please lookup for the same words in the earlier linked document). This option is available with MongoDB v4.2 or higher.